# How to develop with symlinked composer package, but build from a vcs repository?

Tags: php, git, composer-php

While refactoring legacy code, I try to work on a composer package while at the same time work on a project which uses this package.

Composer allows me to add local path repositories for retrieving the package in-development, and [symlinking this package](https://medium.com/pvtl/local-composer-package-development-47ac5c0e5bb4) into my project.

```
<composer.json excerpt>
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../my-package/",
        "options": {
            "symlink": true
        }
    }
],

...
"require": {
    "my/package": "@dev"
}
```

I then do

```
composer update my/package --prefer-source
```

Which symlinks just fine. However, when building my project on a CI server, I want the project to retrieve the package from a remote git repository, this is why I added the vcs section to my `composer.json`.

```
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:my/package.git"
    }
```

However, during building via `composer install` it still tries to retrieve the package locally, which is not available on the CI server of course. I guess because my `composer.lock` explicitly says that the package is retrieved from a path.
How can I make it work smoothly, both locally and on the CI server? I seem to lack a decent workflow.

What I tried so far:

- adding `my/package` again as a dev-package, but apparently the composer.json will remove if from the no-dev packages automatically then. Also, I do not know how to tell composer to use the path repository for the dev requirement, and the vcs repository for the no-dev requirement.

Comment: If the problem is really in composer.lock, I'd rebuild composer.lock during execution on your CI server as first step.

Comment: Thanks for your input Alex, but what do you mean by you "would rebuild composer.lock"? Afaik composer.lock makes sure that I use the same versions, not introducing any updates accidentally.

Comment: I meant that you could "dynamically" change your composer.lock to force package retrieval from remote with a bash script, and then run `composer install`

Comment: Thanks Alex, but that appears to be very tricky to me.

Answer (score 4):

After tons of hours searching for a suitable workflow, I found out one. Hope it can help you.

Since repository-dev (like require-dev for repository) doesn't exist and will not exist soon (see [this](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2619)), we need to make two `composer.json` files. Let's say we call the second one `composer-dev.json`. I think you should **commit** both and having both up-to-date. To tell composer to use `composer-dev.json`, you need to put `COMPOSER=composer-dev.json` in front of every composer command. To illustrate, see this :

composer.json

```json
{
    "repositories":[
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "{repo}"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "vendor/package": "{version}",
    }
}
```

composer-dev.json

```json
{
    "repositories":[
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "path/to/your/package",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "vendor/package" : "{version}",
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `composer.json` contains the 'vcs' repository and the `composer-dev.json` contains the 'path' repository.

#### To initialise your application and start developing :

```sh
COMPOSER=composer-dev.json composer update
```

Composer created the vendor directory and symlink your package folder to `vendor/package`. It also created a `composer-dev.lock` file which you should commit for deployment.

#### To install new package :

```sh
COMPOSER=composer-dev.json composer require vendor/package
```

Remember that `composer.json` **have to be up-to-date**, so you have to put all new lines in it.

#### To build your application :

```sh
COMPOSER=composer-dev.json composer install
```

Which should throw you :

```
[RuntimeException]
Source path "path/to/your/package" is not found for package vendor/package
```

Now you can run :

```sh
composer update --no-dev vendor/package
```

or if you need specific version :

```sh
composer update --no-dev vendor/package:{version}
```

Notice that there is **no** `COMPOSER=composer-dev.json` in front of the last command since we are using `composer.json` in order to use our vcs repository. This last command will also install all missing packages.

I hope it was usefull !

Comment: Pretty cool tricks with `COMPOSER` env variable. Thanks.